# Bash script to check the network status - linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I wrote a bash script:

```
RRR=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2)
if [[ ${RRR} == null ]]; then
`zenity --error --text "NO NETWORK"`
else
`zenity --error --text "NETWORK IS ON"`
fi
```

but its not working fine - when i cut off the network the error message doesn't show on

any suggestions?

thanks' ahead

Comment: Shell usually a somewhat syntax as opposed to C/Java.  `== null` doesn't work the way you'd expect it to.  See `help [[`.  Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but saying `[[ -z ${RRR} ]]` might work for you.

Comment: I usually use the ping command (e.g. ping myhost.com -c3) to check if a host is reachable. You can then use the exit status of ping (success=0) for further evaluation.

Comment: ` when i cut off the network the error message doesn't show on` why it must ON

Comment: Using backticks so suppress the output of zenity is very odd.  It is far more common to simply write: `zenity --error --text "MSG" > /dev/null`

Comment: I have never seen `ifconfig` produce a string like "inet addr: null". I think your `if [[ ... ]]` condition needs some rethinking...

Answer (score 1):

I think ping is help you as alternative But you already solved it  interesting to popup message window with network status.

```
ping -q -w 1 -c 1 `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` > /dev/null && echo "NETWORK IS ON" || echo "NO NETWORK"
```

or

```
 ROUTER_IP="your router ip"
    ( ! ping -c1 $ROUTER_IP >/dev/null 2>&1 ) && service network restart >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
find /proc/irq/ -name \*eth0\* | fgrep -q eth0 && echo up || echo down
```

if the interface is loaded it will apear

```
root@stormtrooper:/proc# ifconfig eth0 down
root@stormtrooper:/proc# find /proc/irq/ -name \*eth0\* | fgrep -q eth0 && echo up || echo down
down
root@stormtrooper:/proc# ifconfig eth0 up
root@stormtrooper:/proc# find /proc/irq/ -name \*eth0\* | fgrep -q eth0 && echo up || echo down
up
```

I don't know if it will refear to linkstate... but use /proc is always faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use ping command to analyze connection quality. 
I use this function to test current interface in linux. It's ping destination address 10 times and return 0 - if succeed, 1- otherwise.  It just one of possibility.

param1 - interface name (eth0, tun0...);
param2 - ping destination

```
ping_interface() {
    # Max value of losted packages in %
    MAX_PACKETS_LOST=80
    PACKETS_COUNT=10
    PACKETS_LOST=$(ping -c $PACKETS_COUNT -I $1 $2 |grep % | awk '{print $7}')
    if ! [ -n "$PACKETS_LOST" ] || [ "$PACKETS_LOST" == "100%" ];
    then
        # 100% failed
        return 1
    else
        if [ "${PACKETS_LOST}" == "0%" ];
        then
            #ping is OK
            return 0
        else
            # Real value of losted packets between 0 and 100%
            REAL_PACKETS_LOST=$(echo $PACKETS_LOST | sed 's/.$//')
            if [[ ${REAL_PACKETS_LOST} -gt ${MAX_PACKETS_LOST} ]];
            then
                echo "Failed. Lost more then limit"
                return 1
            else
                echo "Connection is ok."
                return 0
            fi
        fi
    fi
}

ping_interface eth0 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: You can also check if eth0 up and configured correct using "ifconfig" command. For example: "ifconfig eth0 | grep RUNNING"